# почему образ php-fpm на базе Alpine весит больше?

Tags: docker, php-fpm

Я стараюсь оптимизировать свои docker образы для php-fpm

моя первая попытка собрать образ `php-fpm` с драйверами для postgres весит `428MB`:

```php
FROM php:8.0-rc-fpm

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y nano \ 
    && apt-get install -y iputils-ping \ 

    && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_pgsql
```

Вторая попытка собрать образ `php-fpm на базе Alpine` с драйверами для postgres весит `654MB`:

```php
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.13

RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \

    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_pgsql
```

в стоке  ( без добавленных пакетов ) образы весят:

`php:8.0-rc-fpm:`**315MB**
`php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.13`**84.9MB**

я подозреваю что `apk add postgresql-dev` не совсем одно и тоже что `apt-get install -y libpq-dev` с точки зрения зависимостей и общего количества пакетов и поэтому он весит больше.

**Вопрос как можно собрать более оптимизированный образ php-fpm с драйверами для postgres?**
Буду признателен каждому мнению или замечанию, спасибо!

Comment: Я не мог использовать `apk add libpq-dev` т.к этот пакет в `apk` называется `postgresql-dev`

Comment: После добавление зависимостей вам нужно удалить все временные файлы, которые были подтянуты apk update (но это не точно)